# Is there a spring equivalent to @Startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have to convert an enterprise application to spring. I've got everything working so far. But I still need to replace the @Startup annotation on 2 of my beans.

Is there a spring equivalent or how would you do this in spring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @RC. Can you explain?

Comment: @chrylis It marks a singleton bean (EJB) for eager initialization during the application startup sequence. But Spring starts its beans automatically so i'm wondering if it is needed at all.

Comment: It's not needed. If Spring knows about the bean (either through scanning or because of an explicit declaration), it gets initialized during context initialization.

Comment: `@Startup` means eager initialization. Since the defaults in Java EE and spring are contrary (non singleton lazy in EE and singleton eager in spring), you get this out of the box. `@Component @Transactional` equals roughly `@Singleton @Startup`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explanations! If i could upvote you guys i would!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for. I always use the @PostConstruct annotation in my Spring-beans, to do stuff that needs to be done at startup of the application:

```
@Component
public class SchedulerBootstrap {

    @Autowired
    MyRepository myRepository;

    @Autowired
    OpenPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer;

    @PostConstruct
    /**
     * This method will be called after the bean has been 
     * instantiated and all dependencies injected.
     */
    public void init() {

    }
}
```

Adding an example of how you can write a unit test to experiment with the behaviour of the bean in a Spring context.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-context.xml"})
public class BootstrapTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    SchedulerBootstrap schedulerBootstrap;

    @Test
    public void myTest() { 
        //Some code that berifies that init-method had been called.
        //Or start unit test in debug-mode and add a breakpoint in the 
        //init-method, you will see it being called before the test is executed.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the @PostConstruct aswel and was thinking the same thing. The '@Startup' might not be needed in spring since, i believe, beans are already initialised on startup. Although i would love some confirmation just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it is working. Of course you need to have a spring-context defined that initializes the bean in the first place. Please review the example I added regarding how you can write a unit test to confirm the behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, but JEE '@Startup' annotation is about launching precedence between inter dependent components ... '@PostConstruct' cannot garant that a required component is created and ready  when starting another component.